# Scraping links for array, saving to .json with node-horseman

Tags: arrays, json, node.js

We are making a simple script to go through the sitemap of a website, and grab all the links and there href values, which is then saved into a .json list, which another module can use to take screenshots of those visited pages.

So far, we can get the function that grabs the lists to work. When it is run in the console, the data we want to put into the array shows up.

When run in terminal, nothing is found and the array is not populated.

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var Horseman = require('node-horseman');
var horseman = new Horseman();

function findAllUrls(selector) {

  var urls = [];

  // get all the anchors
  $(selector).each(function() {

    // loop through each anchor and get the href value
    var url = {
      title: $(this).text(),
      url: $(this).attr("href")
    };

    // put the href value in a new array
    urls.push(url);
  });

  // finally return the array of all the href value
  console.log("Log all urls from findAllUrls", urls);
  return urls;
};

horseman
  .open(URL goes here)
  .evaluate(findAllUrls, '.sitemap-links a')
  .then(function(urls) {
    console.log(urls);
    // Save the urls to a json file (lookup node 'fs' module)
    fs.writeFile('urls.json', urls, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('saved to urls.json');
    });
  })
  .close();
```

Something is getting skipped when the test is run. I have a feeling it is to do with the PhantomJS emulating the browser and not keeping the array to then pass through.

Answer (score 0):

Horseman is a Promise-based API. Therefore, findAllUrls has to return a promise. .then is expecting a promise, not an array. What's happening is .then is running before findAllUrls returns, because it doesn't expect anything. I suggest you read up on promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). [This](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) is another excellent article on promises. Finally, [this example](https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman/blob/master/examples/links.js) from the horseman documentation is very similar to what you are trying to do.

Something like this would probably work for what you are trying to do (not tested):

```
function findAllUrls(selector) {
  return horseman.evaluate(function () {
      var urls = [];

      // get all the anchors
      $(selector).each(function() {

      // loop through each anchor and get the href value
        var url = {
          title: $(this).text(),
          url: $(this).attr("href")
        };

      // put the href value in a new array
        urls.push(url);
      });

      // finally return the array of all the href value
      console.log("Log all urls from findAllUrls", urls);
      return urls;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue. It just means somewhere in your evaluate function, horseman encountered an error (but based from experience, it doesn't show what error it is). If there's an error encountered, it will automatically return null.

The solution is carefully check your evaluate function line by line which one generates an error, which might be difficult because horseman does not indicate which line is problematic.

Side note, evaluate function has multiple options for returning a value: callback, promise, and actual value. So it's okay to return the value(s) immediately, no need for a promise, as discussed in the documentation.